# Replastered section of wall surrounded by lining paper

Tags: paint, plaster

Late last year we had dry rot treatment on a wall. This involved a section of plaster being removed and then it being replastered. This means we now have a section of wall with bare plaster, surrounded by wall covered in painted lining paper. I usually paint my own walls but had been planning to get decorators in to fix this. However with lockdown continuing on here in Scotland I'm considering doing it myself. What's the best way of getting this looking neat and tidy for repainting?
[image: replastered wall]